# Automatically open files given as command line arguments in Python

Tags: python, file, filenames, command-line-arguments

I have a lot of Perl scripts that looks something like the following. What it does is that it will automatically open any file given as a command line argument and in this case print the content of that file. If no file is given it will instead read from standard input.

```
while ( <> ) {
    print $_;
}
```

Is there a way to do something similar in Python without having to explicitly open each file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [fileinput](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html?highlight=fileinput#module-fileinput) module in Python's standard library is designed exactly for this purpose, and I quote a bit of code from the URL I just gave:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    process(line)
```

Use `print` in lieu of `process` and you have the exact equivalent of your Perl code.

Comment: The library reference manual has been my bloody bedside reading for a couple of weeks now. It's like so unfair that you have years more  Python experience. o.O (but I appreciate the answers, nevertheless)

Comment: @msw It doesn't actually take years. If you just skim over it enough times you get a feel for what stuff is in there for you already, and what isn't-- even if you haven't actually used the relevant modules. There are always surprises, of course (robotparser? Yikes!). I expect it takes years to have done this accidentally, if anything. ;)

Comment: @msw, I agree with David -- I discovered Python in Dec '99, and less than a year later Steve Holden had already nicknamed me "the martellibot" for my copious answers on comp.lang.python;-).

Answer (score 0):

You could look into sys.argv. It may help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).