# How can I take multiple file as input in python & store in a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to take multiple file as input from command-line like

```
#python script.py file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt .... file_N.txt
```

following program can take only one file as input

## python script.py file1.txt

But I want to take multiple file as input.

```
    import sys
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as file:
    wordcount = file.read()
    words= wordcount.split()
    #print(words)
    count = {}
    for word in words:
        if word in count:
            count[word]=count[word] + 1
        else:
            count[word] = 1
    print(count)
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried already?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically open files given as command line arguments in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533673/automatically-open-files-given-as-command-line-arguments-in-python)

Comment: yes.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533673/automatically-open-files-given-as-command-line-arguments-in-python

Answer (score 0):

They are stored in sys.argv.
They are stored in array and you can access them through index.

```
a = str(sys.argv)
// a[0]: file1.txt
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The sys module already contains all the arguments inside the `sys.argv` which is a list of all arguments passed to the program

The minimum working example I can come up with would be

```
import sys
names = sys.argv
```

This code generates a list of all arguments passed to the program. You could of course filter the input to make sure the names are valid.